# No disk tool lists my old 4 TB spinning HDD. I can't get in contact with it

Tags: partitioning, gparted, external-hdd, fdisk, gnome-disk-utility

I've tried to connect it via an esata cable and via USB. It's not listed with fdisk -l.
How can i mount it?

```
dmesg | tail -n 100
```

Doesn't list anything about my large disk.

I have just installed Lubuntu 22.04 LTS

```
hpelitebook8470p:~# uname -a
Linux hpelitebook8470p 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I works in Lubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Some USB ports do not put out enough power for HDD. I had an adapter that worked well with a SSD, but would not spin up an HDD. Does drive have separate power connection or only thru USB port?

Comment: Question 1: It's an external HDD with a separate power supply, plugged into a wall outlet. Question 2: I mentioned Lubuntu 16.04 because it works there. I'm trying to get it to work under Lubuntu 22.04.

Comment: It spins up fine.

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2489631